# Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com for Alfresco Activiti Enterprise BPM

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I am getting a SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [appDispatcher] in context with path [/activiti-app] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Could not send e-mail in execution 37501] with root cause
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1 . Any pointers on how to resolve this one ?

Comment: What mail server do you want to use?

Comment: I am trying to use gmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to configure Alfresco with the other port (587) instead of 465. I had a similar problem on a server.

There could be an issue with port 465 because IANA has reassigned this port and so it is better to use 587. A firewall in your network could block connections on port 465.

[here the whole story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTPS)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Will try 587 instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my working alfresco-global.properties configuration for gmail:

```
mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.protocol=smtp
mail.transport.protocol=smtp
mail.username=mygmail@gmail.com
mail.password=mypass
mail.encoding=UTF-8
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.port=587
```

Comment: I have the same properties, except the mail.port. I am using 465, will try using 587 instead. Thanks !!